# Custom select - overflow hidden issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, select

I have managed to create a pretty good custom select, it works in almost every sense (JS needs tweaking/optimizing) but one issue I have come across in terms of replicating an actual select element is when the relative parent container is set to `overflow: hidden;`. Logic tells me that standard HTML elements are special and have most likely been set up with ways to override CSS options, however I was wondering if there was some form of hack which would allow for me to replicate it with my custom select list.

**EDIT**
The solution I require is allowing the select to show outside the parent element ***WITH*** overflow hidden set on the parent element.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Jfjq/

**HTML**

```html
<div style="height: 50px; width: 100%: float: left; background: red; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="customSelect" data-auto-submit="no" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px; z-index: 1000;">
        <input class="customSelectInput" type="hidden" name="category"></input>
        <p class="customSelectText"></p>

        <ul class="customSelectList" data-open="no">
            <li class="customSelectOption" data-value="1">1</li>
            <li class="customSelectOption" data-value="2">2</li>
            <li class="customSelectOption" data-value="3">3</li>
            <li class="customSelectOption" data-value="4">4</li>
            <li class="customSelectOption" data-value="5">5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <select style="float: left; height: 25px;">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var custSel = $(".customSelect");

    custSel.each(function () {
        $(this).children(".customSelectList").show();

        var custSelInput = $(this).children(".customSelectInput"),
            custSelText = $(this).children(".customSelectText"),
            custSelList = $(this).children(".customSelectList"),
            custSelOption = custSelList.children(".customSelectOption"),
            selectedOpt = custSelList.children("[data-selected=\"true\"]"),
            findSelected = selectedOpt.length,
            biggestWidth = 0;

        custSelOption.each(function () {
            $(this).parent().siblings(".customSelectText").text($(this).text());
            if ($(this).width() > biggestWidth) {
                biggestWidth = $(this).parent().parent().width();
            }
        });

        if (findSelected == 0) {
            custSelList.children(".customSelectOption:first-child").attr("data-selected", "true");
            selectedOpt = custSelList.children(".customSelectOption:first-child");
        }

        if (custSelList.height() > "200") {
            custSelList.css({
                height: "200px",
                "overflow-y": "scroll"
            });
        }

        custSelInput.val(selectedOpt.attr("data-value"));
        custSelText.text(selectedOpt.text());
        $(this).width(biggestWidth);
        custSelList.hide();
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (e.target != "customSelect") {
            $(".customSelectList").attr("data-open", "no");
            $(".customSelectList").hide();
        }
    });

    $(".customSelectText").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this).siblings(".customSelectList").attr("data-open") == "yes") {
            $(this).siblings(".customSelectList").hide();
            $(this).siblings(".customSelectList").attr("data-open", "no");
        } else {
            $(".customSelectList").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("data-open", "no");
                $(this).hide();
            });

            $(this).siblings(".customSelectList").show();
            $(this).siblings(".customSelectList").attr("data-open", "yes");
            $(this).siblings(".customSelectList").children("[data-selected=\"true\"]").css({
                background: "RGB(20, 100, 150)",
                color: "RGB(255, 255, 255)"
            });
        }
    });

    $(".customSelectList").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).children("[data-selected=\"true\"]").css({
                background: "RGB(255, 255, 255)",
                color: "RGB(0, 0, 0)"
            });

            $(this).children("[data-selected=\"true\"]").hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        background: "RGB(20, 100, 150)",
                        color: "RGB(255, 255, 255)"
                    });
                },
                function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        background: "RGB(255, 255, 255)",
                        color: "RGB(0, 0, 0)"
                    });
                }
            );
        },
        function () {
            $(this).children("[data-selected=\"true\"]").css({
                background: "RGB(20, 100, 150)",
                color: "RGB(255, 255, 255)"
            });
        }
    );

    $(".customSelectOption").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().siblings(".customSelectText").text($(this).text());
        $(this).parent().siblings("input").attr("value", $(this).attr("data-value"));
        $(this).siblings("[data-selected=\"true\"]").removeAttr("data-selected");
        $(this).attr("data-selected", "true");
        if ($(this).parent().parent(".customSelect").attr("data-auto-submit") == "yes") {
            $(this).parent().parent().parent("form").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```css
* {
    color: RGB(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body {
    padding: 5px;
}

select {
    border: 1px solid RGB(150, 150, 150);
    box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 50px;
}

.customSelect {
    background: RGB(255, 255, 255);
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.customSelectText {
    background: RGB(255, 255, 255);
    border: 1px solid RGB(150, 150, 150);
    box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 23px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    transition: background 400ms;
    user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.customSelect:hover .customSelectText {
    background: RGBA(200, 230, 240, 0.4);
    box-shadow: inset 0px -12px 2px RGBA(120, 200, 250, 0.2);
}

.customSelectText:after {
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);
    content:"";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 0;
}

.customSelectList {
    background: RGB(255, 255, 255);
    border-bottom: 1px solid RGB(150, 150, 150);
    border-left: 1px solid RGB(150, 150, 150);
    border-right: 1px solid RGB(150, 150, 150);
    box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
}

.customSelectOption {
    box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: default;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    width: 100%;
}

.customSelectOption:hover {
    background: RGB(20, 100, 150);
    color: RGB(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Comment: You could use absolute positioning, this will remove the element from the flow of the document, so it can cause issues to other elements, but it will work if you set the parent to relative, and the child to absolute and then position it at the right interval.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/8Jfjq/2/

Comment: The only thing I can think of doing is within the `$(".customSelect").each(function()` i could perhaps store the left and top offset co-ordinates, move it to the body, then assign it those co-ordinates so it appears on that part of the page and therefore places it on top of the parent rather than inside it. Can only see this being a pain to implement though. If only they allowed us to style `select` elements explicitly!

Comment: @lharby Nice one! It is definitely a working solution, only issue would be is you would have to set the co-ordinates of each and every custom select box rather than be able to per say float them with a margin of 10px into a corner.

Comment: It depends on the wrapper I suppose. If you can wrap each select in a parent element that has position:relative. There are nice jquery functions to incrementally step elements at intervals. Here is one I wrote some time ago:
var $listItems = $('ul.routes li');
 $listItems.each(function(){
  $addMargin += 25;
  $(this).css('margin-left', $addMargin + 'px');
 });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the value of `position` from `relative` to `absolute` allows the custom select to be seen outside the container with the `overflow: hidden;` attribute set to it. However, this requires you to set the co-ordinates of each individual select to where you want it to be. The best solution may be to remove `overflow: hidden;` if possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/8Jfjq/2

**Old CSS**

```
.customSelect {
    background: RGB(255, 255, 255);
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

**New CSS**

```
.customSelect {
    background: RGB(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```